# Can White Critters Drop Legendary Equipment?

Tags: diablo-iii

Just wondering; can normal enemies drop Legendary quality equipment? What is the breakdown for probability for White/Blue/Yellow/Purple?

Comment: They do drop Legendary (I got both of mine from white mobs) no idea what the probability is.

Comment: Is it a good idea to use "critter" in the title? I associate small decorative NPCs with that word - the ones that tend to explode when clicked too often in Starcraft.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/91670/10260

Answer (score 9):

Normal enemies **CAN** drop a Legendary. Breaking barrels can drop a legendary. There is a chance of it happening, albeit a small one.

**NOTE: As of patch 1.0.3, the chance for loot drops from containers is even smaller.**

As you have probably noticed, the Elite and Unique enemies tend to have a better chance of dropping better loot. You are more likely to get something good off these mobs, but that doesn't mean a normal enemy couldn't give you a great and rare weapon.

As far as the probability or formula, no one really knows the answer except an official source that would never disclose it.

Comment: A friend of mine got a legendary item from a barrel. We could almost not believe it but it is possible. But it's highly unlikely.

Comment: A friend of mine got a legendary from a barrel with a level 13 character :|

Comment: I have received two legendary armor pieces from normal mobs.  The third one I found was from an elite pack.

Comment: I got a legendary mojo (Thing of the Deep) from a white mob in Cathedral.

Comment: It is worth noting that loot from "containers" has been reduced in patch 1.0.3.