# Can a Legendary or Rare item be found in any clickable object such as a jug, barrel or a crate?

Tags: diablo-iii

I want to know if it is worth clicking on every object I see.

Empirically, it seems that the jugs drop less loot than barrels, and I ask this because I haven't found any good loot from them yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do White Critters Drop Legendary Equip?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71731/do-white-critters-drop-legendary-equip)

Comment: I think this question is better worded, as it is generic.

Comment: It is possible, but due to some abuses destructible objects got nerfed and they drop very poorly. It works way better with containers like boxes, dead bodies etc. IMO it is not worth destroying jars anymore as you are better off killing stuff.

Comment: It was answered in [Do White Critters Drop Legendary Equip?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71731/do-white-critters-drop-legendary-equip/71733#71733) But the question is somewhat different. Answering this one separately may help google searchers find this answer more easily.

Comment: @Tater596 That is why dupes are not deleted.  We keep them around for google-ability.

Comment: Yes it is possible.  I have recieved a Lengendary from a barrel before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the lowliest barrel can drop a rare or a legendary.

Blizzard has said so many times and many people have found incredible loot in otherwise lowly containers. Of course, a rare monster has a *much* higher chance of dropping good loot than a barrel, but there's a chance nonetheless.

Comment: Anything can drop from anywhere, with the exception of uniquely named items (Rakanishu's Blade, etc). This includes barrels, piles of rocks, skeletons, white mobs, rare mobs, elite mobs, unique mobs, super unique (boss) mobs, chests, happy clouds, piñatas, pot o' golds, boxes, loose tiles, urns, pots, hidden stashes, dead bodies...

Comment: Yup, my friend got a legendary item from a barrel.

Comment: @ickleislands `with the exception of uniquely named items` any reference for this?  Where is that coming from?

Comment: @fcrick nope - just from experience, for example 'Rakanishu's Blade' will drop from the 'Shrine of Rakanishu' event in Act 2.

Comment: I found a lvl 60 Tal Rasha's Guardianship in a barrel in 1.0.3

Answer (score 2):

Based on my knowledge the destrucible objects like jugs, barrels and so on **can drop rare items too**. Unfortunately I haven't found any kind of legendary or set item (not even from a boss and I'm level 60 and on Inferno), but I got several rareitems from those stuff. So, yes, it *may* be worth destroying them.

Answer (score 1):

In Act 1 Inferno with 5 stack of Neph Valor, I found a 140 dex, 80 str, +14-20 dmg, socketed yellow ring from a lose tile on the floor.  I don't have any magic find gear yet, so just had the (80% ? can't remember exactly) that comes from Neph Valor.  I'd recommend clicking / destroying everything.

I would say yes, its deffinatly possible to get good stuff from pots and other crap locations :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can, found Tal Rashas Guardianship in a supply crate in act 3 inferno, and I had 0 mf gear as I was clearing at the time with no nephalems.  I was psyched to say the least :)