# Drop rates for set / legendary items

Tags: diablo-iii

Just wondering what the drop rates were for Set / Legendary items, or is it totally random?
I imagine they would increase for later acts in Inferno. My monk is comfortable in Act 3 in Inferno, but I've only found one set item, so MF will increase chances for them?

Answer (score 24):

In patch 1.05 the drop rates were doubled and Monster Power added a new bonus.

Using the base numbers from the Blizzard forums:

```
                                                Max                     Max
                                                Non-inf                 Inferno
       base MF  100%    200     300     400     475     500     600     625%
normal 0.0036%  0.0072  0.0108  0.0144  0.0180  0.0207  0.0216  0.0252  0.0261%
elite  0.0440%  0.0880  0.1320  0.1760  0.2200  0.2530  0.2640  0.3080  0.3190%
```

It is now trivial to get 100 MF with paragon levels and NV stacks, so I usually assume the 100MF line as the new baseline.  With the 300% cap in place, bonuses from NV and bonuses from MP the new max MF is 475% in Normal, Nightmare and Hell (produced experimentally by hitting the cap in Act 1 Normal Monster Power 10).  The shrine does not bump this to 500%.  I am uncertain if the upper limit is 625% or 650%, as I cannot get 5 NV stacks in Monster Power 10, Inferno, but if it behaves like Normal then the max is 625%, calculated as max. 300% from equipment + paragon levels + 250% from MP 10 in Inferno + 75% from 5 NV stacks.

[image: mf vs pop chance]

Empirically, running between 325 and 375 I've been seeing a legendary or set item about every 4 or 5 hours of game play, using Act 3, Monster Power 3.  Most of them stink, but that's another discussion all together.  I've also had sessions where I've popped 3 in a matter of an hour at MF 260% MP 3 Inferno.  I also see a legendary about every full act run at max MF in Normal (sometimes none but usually 1 maybe 2).

Keep in mind that each monster kill is an independent event.  The odds are not cumulative, so killing 50,000 white mobs at 475% MF does not guarantee you a legendary pop (though I'd be somewhat startled if you didn't get one).  You still only have a small chance on each individual kill to see a legendary or set pop.  People often misinterpret the probability of independent events to think that doing more of the same will increase their odds.  The odds on each kills stays the same.  What changes is the odds against seeing another consecutive failure.  See this [question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/227177/13073) for a mathematical treatment.

So let's look at the odds of seeing a legendary or set pop after repeated mob kills.

[image: oddsVersusKills]

So what is this graph saying?  Looking at the 100% MF for normal mobs line, it says that after about 3,000 white mob kills there is a roughly 20% chance that you will have seen a legendary pop.  On the Elite 625% MF line it says that there is roughly an 80% chance that you will have seen a legendary pop after 500 elite kills.  It is very important to note that none of these values ever equal 100%, even at 32000 kills the number is still "very close" to 100% but not quite.

Tracking these curves it is very clear that even for large numbers of kills the probability of seeing a legendary pop can be very low for normal mobs regardless of MF, but that it is much better to hunt elites for even less than 1,000 elite kills at any MF.  It is for this reason that most serious legendary farmers are getting their 5 NV stacks and killing as many elite packs as they can find, not lingering about with white hordes.

So does this match up with the assertion that you kill 10-30 times the whites is as good as killing elites?  Looking at the 60% probability line, at 100% MF against elites, if you are killing 10 times then that's better than the 100% MF against white mobs, it's acutally on par with 300% MF against whites.  If you are killing 30 times then the 100% MF normal line is actually above the elite line.  My battle net account shows that overall, including levelling at all difficulties I am averaging about 20 whites : 1 elite, just as an arbitrary number for consideration.  As a level 60 I target elites, so I suspect this ratio is decreasing but it will take some time for all the levelling to be averaged out.

The maximum pop chance from a white mob at maximum MF is still about half of the base chance for an elite.  This fits with my empirical experience.  I have popped legendaries off white mobs but far more off concentrated attacks on elite packs.

One thing that changes the scenario somewhat, that I've failed to make note of in this answer is that an elite kill gives multiple pops many (not all) of which have a chance of being legendary.  Normal kills only give 1 or 2 chances.  As both NV and MP add extra items into kills.  If we assume that an elite gives twice as many items as a normal (an easy assumption) then with my white:elite ratio we should only use the 10x comparison, and then clearly the elite killing strategy is modestly better.  If we make assumptions about 5 NV stacks or higher MP levels then this gap widens.

It is very clear there are diminishing returns for adding MF.  The distance between the lines shows there is a large gain for going from 100 to 300 MF, a smaller but decent gain between 300 and 475 MF but a very minuscule gain for pushing to 625%.

If there are hidden mechanics working behind the scenes or if the base rate is incorrect, then this picture will evolve with time.

Comment: 475% max sounds low to me. Inferno monster power says you get 25% per level (https://bnetcmsus-a.akamaihd.net/cms/content_folder_media/MQRC9PZ3CZ1K1349891151349.jpg?v=0), so I would think that means +250% at MP10, giving you 300 + 250 + 75 from NV = 625%. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Oh I didn't notice you said you were doing normal difficulty. Then 475 makes perfect sense. The OP said Inferno, which uses different rates according to the chart I posted, so maybe it can get to 625% in Inferno but only 475% in the other difficulties? Or are you saying even Inferno gets capped for some reason?

Comment: Great work, @Stephen.  This actually makes me want to finish Inferno with my wimpy demon hunter, so she can stop being wimpy.

Comment: @MBraedley My wimpy DH is surviving the crush of Inferno :)  Keep at it! :)

Comment: Wait a minute though... these are raw ratios, not percentages? As in, at 625% an elite mob has a 31.9% chance of a legendary? Or is it a 0.319% chance? Your "500 white mobs at 475% MF" suggests that is the case. If so... wow.

Comment: Don't shift the decimal place.  At 625% MF an elite mob has a 0.319% chance of popping a legendary.  The 500 white mobs comment is about if the chance was cumulative to 100% and is a little off the cuff, might need to be 500,000

Comment: Ok yeah that's what I had expected. Now that I look again I see the % signs on each end of the graph.

Comment: All of this data looks very correct. Great job! I have found 10 - 15 legendary items this week(most in Inferno, others while leveling a friend in Nightmare).

Comment: I don't understand why you added the line of diminishing gains?  That's not the case.  If you add 100% more mf, you are 100% more likely (when compared to 0%) to find a rare/legendary.  If you have 500% mf, you'll find 5x more rares/legendaries than someone with 0% mf.

Comment: @spartacus There is an even gain for any independent event, however, if you look at the 2nd graph detailing the probability over time, you'll see that at (ie) 300 MF you reach an 80% probability much faster than if you were at 100 MF.  The difference between those two is much larger than the difference between 300 and 500 MF.  Hence, there is a diminished return for gaining 200 MF when starting at 300 compared with 100 when considered over time.

Comment: @Stephen: Very nice post! Though I wonder if these numbers are really correct. First, the elite percentage: it's the chance to get a legendary item after you kill one stack of elites, not the chance of one stack divided by three? For instance, my monk has 6000 elite kills, which means 2000 stacks of elite. I usually run around at 200-300 MF only, and I found ~40 legendaries so far. Isn't this a bit off?

Comment: @Stephen: Then, regarding the ratio of 20:1 of whites : elites you mentioned: If an elite kill means 'one elite mob' in the battle.net profile (which I am pretty sure of), then you'd actually have a ratio of 60:1 whites : 'elite loot', and if the percentage above means 'chance of getting a legendary in one elite loot', it should change your paragraph about the relation between white and elite legendary drops a bit (if I am right about this, that is. It is just an assumption what the number means ;)). But I may have mistaken you somewhere.

Comment: @Stephen: Correction to my first comment: "it's" should be "is it", and "not" should be "or" there ;) Once again, I'm only wondering, since the number of legendaries I have found so far is way above what I should be expecting out of these percentages, even if the chance should actually be multiplied by 3 (which I don't believe). Is there still the 'bonus rare' from a pack of elites when having 5 stacks of NV maybe? And perhaps the 'bonus item' of the MP system also counts in there, though I usually don't run higher than MP3; this shouldn't affect much. Hum.

Comment: @Randal'Thor As I said in the post, ***"One thing that changes the scenario somewhat, that I've failed to make note of in this answer is that an elite kill gives multiple pops many (not all) of which have a chance of being legendary."***  I'm making an assumption that whites and elites give the same number of pops for these charts, which we all know is false, however, the actual situation is quite a bit more complex than it first appears.  Since the numbers hold under that assumption though, it's clear that multiple pops from elites only make it better.

Comment: @Randal'Thor While I've had streaks of above these curves, I've also had streaks below ... some people on battle.net claiming to be far below it.  I think that the pop rate refers the maximum possibility on each item that pops from an elite which could otherwise be a legendary (eg it wouldn't apply to the potion or gem pop slots), so with 5 NV you certainly have what, 3-5 chances per elite kill each at the pop rate.  That's my understanding anyway.  When I scale the numbers for that sort of rationale it fits more closely with my experiences, but it's always good to be conservative on paper :)

Comment: MF is HARDCAPPED at 375% with MV stacks. You can't ger more.

Comment: @Luke That's wrong, I've had it higher no problem.  You need to use the bonus from MP to get above the hardcap.

Answer (score 3):

**THIS ANSWER IS CURRENT AS OF PATCH 2.0.3**

No solid numbers are available since the 2.0 patch and Reaper of Souls have come around, but what we have is a smattering of blue posts dealing with legendary drop rates and, in one case, a now deleted (but quoted repeatedly) blue post that sheds more light on how magic find affects drop rates in 2.0. It is unlikely that Blizzard will ever officially disclose their base rate for certain drops, so the best we can say is as follows:

- The [blue posts confirm that the chance has been elevated](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12319691934) as of 3/28/14, and
  [can be elevated further by playing on the various levels of Torment
  difficulty](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12091349617?page=5#89).
- [Certain legendaries and sets can only be found in Torment I or
  higher](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/10189299133) and like other legendaries their drop rate is increased with each level of Torment.

The "Magic Find" stat that used to be a staple on items in vanilla D3 have been totally removed from any new blue or yellow items in 2.0. There are still some legendaries that have this affix, but they are very limited. You can also still use a Topaz gem in your helmet to increase your chances, but the effect on rare and legendary items has been extremely nerfed. If you want to know how magic find is treated in 2.0, and how it is vastly different from vanilla, see my answer on the question "[How does Magic Find work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66176/how-does-magic-find-work)".

Comment: As of 22 May 2014, the legendary drop rate of legendaries is increased by 100%. http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12926172697#1

Answer (score 0):

I know only of this source with somewhat reliable information: [Legendary Drop Rates](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/46473-legendary-drop-rates/)

It basically states that it is more common to get your legendary from a normal mob.

They claim that the drop rates for legendary items without high MF is:

- 0.022% for Elites
- 0.0018% for Normal mobs

Usually you kill way more Normal mobs than Elites ~ 10-30X more.

You can translate this into your own drop chance. I made some estimations for my runs and found that 1 legendary drops for ever 120-150 h of play. Many claim to have a way better drop rate, but there are others that still wait for their fist drop.

It can be assumed that a really high MF (>300%) will increase your chances considerably as this is basically a factor.

Having said that: You will usually get more legendary items in lower Acts, because you can afford a higher MF in a lower act. If you can "survive" Act 3 with < 100 MF the same char should easily be able to stack 300 MF in Act I and still slaughter everything. High kill rate + high MF means more legendary items.

Comment: I just want to add following, taken from the [official website](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/items/equipment#magic-find), to clarify how MF works: with 300% MF and a 0.022% drop probability from Elites, you have a 0.088% probability of droping a legendary item from an Elite