# More chances to get legendary items

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Diablo 3 - Drop rates for set / legendary items](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79709/diablo-3-drop-rates-for-set-legendary-items)

I have been doing hours and hours farming in Inferno Act 1 and 2, and occasionally in Act 3 up to  Siege Breaker, but so far I haven't had any good luck getting decent legendary items, let alone any set items.

I understand that the drop rate of legendary items is extremely rare, but even so, I think I could have done better than that.

So here I am asking a question, how am I able to farm legendary items more efficiently? Are there any particular events that probably have better chances to drop legendary / set items?

Thanks in advance for any tips and suggestions.

Comment: in short: get more MF and kill faster.  Its purely random, I haven't had a legendary in a week of 1.04, but on sunday I found 3.  My MF must've only changed by a few % in that time frame due to paragon levels.

Comment: Hmm, I hear you. Is there any chance that regular mob would drop legendary items? Or it only happens to rare and champion packs?

Comment: the chance is certainly there.  out of the 3 legendaries I got, one was from a breakable (pile of bones in act 3), one was from a champion, and one was from a regular monster.  And a side note, the one from the regular monster was the one that sold for the most gold.

Comment: Sounds great! I wish I had that good luck, haha. In 1.0.5, DH's ToC ability is said to be nerfed, so I guess the fun time is probably not that long :(

Comment: I found 2 on Sunday as well (I have found a total of 8). Conspiracy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As yx already wrote, the best you can do is increase your Magic Find since this directly increases the drop rate. If your equipment (or Nephalem Valor) grants you, say, 100% MF, it will double the probabilities of getting legendaries (as well as rare and magic items). Keep in mind that, as you say, the drop rates are low. Following the preivous example, if a mob has a chance of 0,01% of droping a legendary, with your 100%MF the drop rate will increase to 0,02%.

That´s where the second advice of yx comes in: kill fast! The more you kill, the more times you have the chance of droping a legendary.

As a side note, try to farm as far in the game as possible (as long asyou are confortable playing): monsters in later acts tend to drop more good items so, although you could still be unluky, legendaries droped from monsters in acts 3 and 4 will probably have a higher item level than those from earlier acts.

[Here is a link](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/items/equipment#magic-find) to the game guide with more information about the magic find, in case you find it useful.

Happy farming!

EDIT: in ayckoster's answer to [this other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79709/diablo-3-drop-rates-for-set-legendary-items) you can find more info about legendary items' drop rates.

Comment: I guess I must have had my luck back or sth. I did an hour quick run in Inferno Act 2, and doh, I got this, http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bulkathoss-wedding-band

Comment: Anyway, totally unexpected and surprised. I guess legendary drop is indeed very random. Thanks for the suggestions, guys.

Comment: Congrats! You have been luckier than me so far =P I added a link with extra information about the drop rates. I thought you may find it helpful.