# How has RoS changed Diablo 3's legendary drop rate?

Tags: diablo-iii

It seems like the legendary/set drop rates have gone crazy since:

- The auction houses closed and
- The Reaper of Souls update.

[These rates](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79709/diablo-3-drop-rates-for-set-legendary-items) seem way out of date now.

Does anyone have some solid numbers on how they have changed?

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like they [buffed the rate](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12319691934) recently.

Comment: Patch 2.0 brought a **total overhaul** of legendary drop rates and mechanics. Nothing posted before is of any indication of how things are now. I have no time to research and write a proper answer, but here's what I know from skimming through development notes: 1) plain drop chance is considerably higher, 2) there's a failsafe mechanism that increases drop chance, when you haven't got a legendary for a couple of hours, 3) there are guaranteed legendaries from act bosses for characters below max level, 4) don't forget gambling.

Comment: Since the legendary drop rate changed with 2.0, and there's no difference between base D3 and RoS, I believe an updated answer is in order.

Answer (score 0):

No solid numbers are available. But it is all tied into how Blizzard has dealt with Magic Find on gear, and what difficulty you are playing on.

The [blue posts confirm that the chance has been elevated](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12091349617?page=5#89), and [can be elevated further by playing on the various levels of Torment difficulty](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12319691934). Also, [certain legendaries and sets can only be found in Torment I or higher](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/10189299133).